# Jquery ajax function returns wrong page, though the url in a browser window shows correct page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a chrome extension in javascript.

I'm trying to get the page contents from an Outlook mailserver through an ajax request, but I have trouble getting the correct page returned.

I suspect it is the danish letter æ, that creates the problem, but don't know how to resolve it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + 'Indbakke/',
    data: "Cmd=contents&View=Ulæste%20meddelelser", //Avoid encodeURI
    dataType: 'html',
    processData: false, //Avoid encodeURI
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
             fetchedInbox = $.parseHTML(data);

             //If there are changes to the inbox, refresh the inbox page
             if(findString(fetchedInbox, 'ingen emner')) 
             {
                 window.parent.frames[1].location = baseURL + 'Indbakke/?Cmd=contents';
             }
    },
    complete : function(){
             console.log("URL" + this.url)
    }
  });
```

The data variable of the *succes* function contains the wrong page, but if I copy 'this.url' from the *complete* function into a browser, it displays the right page. I have tried using default ajax settings and encodeURI on the full link (without using the 'data' option), but then neither 'data' or 'this.url' will work (i.e. I change the second parameter to 'View=Ul%C6ste%20meddelelser').

I do not have access to the (probably) asp page that the server sends, just javascript, so I can't do anything serverside.

Note: When chromes console show this.url, it breaks the link before æ, so I have to manually copy the url

Comment: Try to replace `æ` by `%C3%A6`.

Comment: What the... that worked. Why did that work, and where did you find the character code? I used this list: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: I'll make an answer so you can mark this question as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the `æ` that creates this error. Replace `æ` by `%C3%A6` and the headers will be send to the correct location.

```
data: "Cmd=contents&View=Ul%C3%A6ste%20meddelelser"
```

To find the encoded character, I used this converter: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/